# Can I provide bank statements from multiple accounts when applying for a UK visa?

Tags: visas, uk, proof-provenance-of-funds

I have multiple accounts under the same bank for different purposes, which should I present?

Does the visa officer want to check if I have enough money in my savings maintained consistently over a period or to see my day to day expenses and transactions showing flight/accommodation bookings?

My accounts are:

- Account 1 - Savings

Where my salary is deposited. I transfer some money every month to another high interest personal account for saving purposes. These account statements only show my salary being deposited and then money transfers to my internal accounts (transaction account and credit card).

My bills and day to day expenses, everything I pay from my credit card (and settle in full or partially on due date) is by transfer from here.

- Account 2 - High interest savings

Opened early 2016, it shows money coming in, in various amounts, every month and holds a balance around 10 K.

- Account 3 - Everyday transactions

I transfer money here from Savings for expenses I cannot pay by credit card, such as rent and car loan, and any cash withdrawals. I do not keep any balance in this account hence I do not want to submit a statement for it.

I feel as I should present my high interest savings account (Account 2) opened last year as it has the significant balance but when I print off the statements it just shows money coming in to the account with description *Savings* or *Europe*.

Would the officers reject it stating they can't determine how money got into it?

I can also give the statements of my Savings account where salary is being deposited but even that wouldn't show my monthly expenses.

Do they need to see my monthly expenses?

My expenses are all on credit card except for rent, so do I need to submit credit card statements as well?

I read before they really don't care about credit cards but are concerned about bank accounts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

Comment: If anything, I suspect submitting data from multiple accounts if that's how your funds are normally situated is preferable to moving them all into a single account and only submitting that one.  While doing so in your case wouldn't be breaking any rules, there are lots of people who try and cheat the system by borrowing money for just long enough to inflate their account balance.  Doing so, even for legitimate reasons is going to attract unwanted attention while the person approving your application tries to determine if you're trying to cheat the system.

Answer (score 7):

If you can benefit from including multiple bank accounts, in your case provenance of funds and transparency, then of course. There is no requirement to submit statements from a single account.

> My expenses are all on credit card except for rent, so do i need to
>   submit credit card statements as well?

They are not interested in constructing your personal balance sheet and credit card statements that show only expenses are not necessary. The UK officer will ignore credit card statements altogether; the Schengen officer will examine them if you have large credit balances that you want to present as accessible cash.

> I do not want to overload my documents submitting too many bank
>   statements or submitting any irrelevant ones

Based on what you wrote, you should show both accounts. This is not 'overloading' your supporting documents.

Comment: Thank you for your advise.i am able to show statements for both accounts. .i have another issue where i transferred ( lent) 5 K to a person in need last october and he will pay me back by end of this month.when they see 5K appearing in my account would they see it as fund parking? What proof i should submit to show its my own money been returned to me.Ill be lodging for visa around begining of May.would this create an issue for me?

Comment: @DDh88 no, this is not how the site works. You asked your question and you got your answer. We cannot go along expanding things in comments because they will not be visible  Please use the 'ask question' button and please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers