# Which bank statement to submit for UK visa?

Tags: uk, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am a foreigner staying in Germany and wants to travel to the UK. I want to know what bank statement is required of me, a bank statement from my country or a German Bank statement?

Comment: Do you understand WHY your bank statement is required in the application?

Answer (score 5):

First, go read [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab), which will tell you what they're looking to see from your bank statements.

There's no requirement that your bank statement be from a particular country; the requirement is that it be yours and it show your financial situation. So you should submit whatever bank statement demonstrates your financial stability and ability to afford your trip. If you have a job, your bank statement should show regular deposits of wages that match the information you supply on your application. If you have savings or investments, your bank statement should show them.

If you have multiple accounts, it may be advantageous to [submit multiple bank statements](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88503/can-i-provide-bank-statements-from-multiple-accounts-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa). For example, if your salary is deposited into one account, while your savings are in another, you might submit both so the decision-maker can see a more complete picture of your situation.